# Expectation of Ito Integrals.

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Consider the stochastic differential equation:$$dx(t)=f(x(t))dt+g(x(t))dB(t)$$
where $B(t)$ is the standard brownian motion.

Is the following always true:

$$\mathbb{E}\int_0^tH(x(t))dB(t)=0$$

If it is not true in general, what are the conditions on the function $H(x)$ that makes the equality holds?

Comment: Obviously there need be SOME conditions on $H$ for the integral to be well-defined. At the very least it should be measurable, I would think.

Answer (score 3):

If the stochastic integral wrt to the B.M. is well defined, then your claim is always true. For the integral to be well defined we need the integrand process H to be $\{\mathscr{F}_t\}$-adapted and also to satisfy
$$\int_0^t |H_u|^2 du < \infty.$$